# retaining case in elasticsearch faceted search

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

Is there a way to do faceted searches using the elasticsearch Search API maintaining case (as opposed to having the results be converted to lowercase).

Thanks in advance, Chuck

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using the ["terms" facet](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/terms-facet.html), the facet entries are exactly the terms in the index. Briefly, analysis is the process of converting a field value into a sequence of terms, and lowercasing is a step in the default analyzer; that's why you're seeing lowercased terms. So you will want to change your [analysis configuration](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/index.html) (and perhaps introduce a [multi_field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type.html) if you want to run several different analyzers.)

There's a great explanation in Lucene in Action (2nd Ed.); it's applicable to ElasticSearch, too.